# YOLOV4 model training

Tags: machine-learning, python, machine-learning-model, data-science-model, opencv

[image]

I can't start my model tutorial. I ran it correctly, I tried it before, but now it doesn't even start. why could it be? Did the update come?

Comment: Add more details about the tutorial you referred.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.